# Google In App Billing does not return any items

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am desperate enough now to post my very first question here :-) I did an App and published it to Google Play Store. I also have an In-App product that is a monthly subscription. The funny thing now is that buying the product from the App works fine, but when i do a queryInventoryAsync i do not get any product info in return. No matter if the person has bought the product or not. Here the code where i try to load product details

```
            List<String> additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
            additionalSkuList.add(PRODUCT_AD_FREE);

            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList,
                    new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

                            if (result.isFailure() || inventory == null) {
                                // handle error
                                AsyncService.messageDialog(RemoveAdsActivity.this,"Query Inventory Failure!",SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE,null);
                                return;
                            }

                            AsyncService.messageDialog(RemoveAdsActivity.this,"Query Inventory Success!",SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE,null);

                            if (inventory.getSkuDetails(PRODUCT_AD_FREE) != null) {

                               price = inventory.getSkuDetails(PRODUCT_AD_FREE).getPrice();

                                AsyncService.messageDialog(RemoveAdsActivity.this,"Price Success!" + price, SweetAlertDialog.NORMAL_TYPE,null);

                                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.removeAdsButton)).setText(getString(R.string.remove_ads_button, price));
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    });
```

I never got any product back. Any idea what i could possibly be doing wrong? Subscription products should also be returned by such a query, shouldn´t they?

`getSkuDetails` is always `null` in this case

Here is the log:

```
02-17 11:50:03.497    9657-9657/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ Starting in-app billing setup.
02-17 11:50:03.507    9657-9657/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ Billing service connected.
02-17 11:50:03.507    9657-9657/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
02-17 11:50:03.507    9657-9657/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ In-app billing version 3 supported for net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal
02-17 11:50:03.527    9657-9657/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ Starting async operation: refresh inventory
02-17 11:50:03.537   9657-10006/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ Querying owned items...
02-17 11:50:03.537   9657-10006/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ Package name: net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal
02-17 11:50:03.537   9657-10006/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
02-17 11:50:03.537   9657-10006/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ Owned items response: 0
02-17 11:50:03.537   9657-10006/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ Continuation token: null
02-17 11:50:03.537   9657-10006/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ Querying SKU details.
02-17 11:50:03.557   9657-10006/net.dowalil.raceteamprincipal D/IabHelper﹕ Ending async operation: refresh inventory
```

And to mention it again: purchasing works.

Answer (score 1):

ok, i solved the issue now by myself. its odd and strange but the iabhelper as used in the triviadrive example simply seems not to work for subscriptions, the problem is the product-type that is set fix to in-app

in my iabhelper i changed this:

```
// Item type: in-app item
//public static final String ITEM_TYPE_INAPP = "inapp";
public static final String ITEM_TYPE_INAPP = "subs";
```

and suddenly i get only the subscriptions... ok

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this check YOUR LICENSE KEY. If it the wrong key it will create the order and process the charge but will not register the item and will return no inventory. In my case I used the key from my other app and got the result you are seeing. As soon as i changed it to the correct key everything worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, but the key is allright as i am pretty sure. I now just tried to add 3 more products: an unmanaged one, a managed one and another subscription. and the result: the unmanaged and the managed products appear in the inventory query, but the subscription does not?!